# Can't scroll on Javascript with synchronous sleep

Tags: javascript, synchronous

I'am writting a code to scroll down with synchronous pauses between scrolls. To achieve synchronous sleep I am using the classic Javascript approach using a While loop with a timer. Here's where it gets wierd, the function works with everything except for scrolling.

ex 1. This WORKS:

```
function sleep(t) {
  const start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - start < t);
}

console.log("hello")
sleep(2000);
console.log("hello 2")
sleep(2000);
console.log("hello 3")
sleep(2000);
console.log("hello 4")
sleep(2000);
```

Ex 2. This does NOT WORK:

```
function sleep(t) {
  const start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - start < t);
}
elem = document.getElementById("main-div");
elem.scrollBy(0,120);
sleep(2000);
elem.scrollBy(0,120);
sleep(2000);
elem.scrollBy(0,120);
sleep(2000);
elem.scrollBy(0,120);
sleep(2000);
```

Any Idea what is happening?

Comment: What is a _"synchronous pause between scrolls"_? It doesn't make sense to lock the event loop when you could just delay each scroll step with `setTimeout()`

Comment: @Phil need it to be locked because the JS wil run on a different machine and I want it to halt all other execution until it is done scrolling

Comment: Sounds like you're going about this the wrong way. What _other_ execution do you want to avoid? Could you not set some kind of flag / semaphore? I'd be pretty sure that even writing an infinite loop wouldn't stop worker threads either

Comment: @Phil The code is wrapped in some python script which will start to execute if the sleep() is done in an asynchronous manner. At this point I am really, just interested in the inner workings of this particular piece of code. Why does it work when printing to the console, but wont work when scrolling?

Comment: Python doesn't run in the browser so I do not see how that's related at all

Comment: Like I said I'm just interested in the working of this particular JS code, just want to to understand why one works , but not the other. Do you have any input on that @Phil ?

Comment: @LawlessLeopard The browser just waits for synchronous scripts to finish before displaying any effects your code might have on the DOM. It's not guaranteed that the console logs are displayed immediately either.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "the code is wrapped in some python script", this in a browser environment. When you run JS code it blocks the current browser window, e.g. all async actions like user interactions, scrolling, timer callbacks are paused until you yield back to the event loop, and give other events in the queue a chance to run.

Instead of blocking the event loop you could start an interval timer, and disable actions you'd like to prevent from happening until the time is over.

Here is an example: When you click on the "Busy for 8 sec" button, the other "Submit" button is disabled until the time is over, or until you hit the "Busy for 8 sec" button again to stop the timer.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#busyButton').click(function() {
    if(timerId) {
      stopTimer();
      return;
    } else {
      startTimer();
    }
  });
});

let timerId;

function startTimer() {
  $('#submitButton').prop("disabled", true).css({color: 'gray'});
  $('#busyButton').css({color: 'red'});
  let count = 0;
  timerId = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('count', ++count);
    if(count >= 8) {
      stopTimer();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  timerId = null;
  $('#submitButton').prop("disabled", false).css({color: 'black'});
  $('#busyButton').css({color: 'black'});
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 7em !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
<hr />
<button id="busyButton">Busy for 8 sec</button>
```